# Allow user to run command as another user with their environment in sudoers

Tags: permissions, sudo, environment-variables

So, I have an entry that looks like this in my sudoers file:

```
user1 ALL=(user2) NOPASSWD: /scripts/dir/
```

This allows user1 to run all executables under `/scripts/dir/` as user2 without entering their password using a command like `sudo -u user2 /scripts/dir/script`. However, I ran into issues where the executables expect to be run with user2's environment (`$PATH, $DISPLAY`, etc). user1 can accomplish that by running something like `sudo -iu user2 /scripts/dir/script` which simulates a login shell, but with the above sudoers entry, this doesn't work and they're prompted to enter their password. Is there a sudoers entry that will alow user1 to run this command or at least be able to source user2's .bashrc, .cshrc, etc. when running commands?

I have found the `SETENV` option, but that allows user1 to preserve their existing environment, not take on user2's environment. I could do `source /home/user2/.bashrc` followed by `sudo -Eu user2 /scripts/dir/script`; this would give user1 user2's environment which will be preserved by the `-E` option, but this assumes that user1 has read access to the `.bashrc` file and that the script does not try to execute any commands that user1 does not have permission to run.

The sudoers man page states the following about the `-i` option to `sudo`:

> As a special case, if sudo's -i option (initial login) is specified, sudoers will initialize the environment regardless of the value of env_reset. The DISPLAY, PATH and TERM variables remain unchanged; HOME, MAIL, SHELL, USER, and LOGNAME are set based on the target user. On AIX (and Linux systems without PAM), the contents of /etc/environment are also included. On BSD systems, if the use_loginclass flag is enabled, the path and setenv variables in /etc/login.conf are also applied. All other environment variables are removed.

which seems to indicate that it's possible to provide the `-i` option with some sudoers configuration, perhaps by giving user1 permission to run `ALL` commands or specifically allowing the `-i` option in sudoers, but I'm hoping there is a more fine-grained way of achieving this. Also, it seems to indicate that `PATH` and `DISPLAY` will come from user1's environment which is not what I want.

Of course, I could give user1 more permissions than necessary in order to accomplish this, but that presents security risks.

Answer (score 0):

So, I couldn't find a secure way of doing this, so I ended up using the `SETENV:` option in the sudoers entry and then before I issue commands as user1, I source user2's `.bashrc` and provide the `-E` option when invoking sudo. This is not a secure way of accomplishing what I wanted to do because user1 can setup their `PATH` environment variable in a way to allow them to execute arbitrary executables as user2.